# React/Redux - Save select Field value onChange

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I've created a Component that lets you Add/Remove select fields (onClick of an add button). I'm using Redux to keep the state of the dropdown so that when I navigate back and forth (React Router) the added dropdowns are not lost.

It seems to be updating all the select dropdowns with the same data (not individually). So whenever a user types in an attribute:
We use a react table to add in the
1. AttributeName ProficiencySelect
2. AttributeName2 ProficiencySelect2
In the code we only have one select component; however, each time you add an attribute we add a select component. The problem we are facing is differentiating the data for each select. We tried fixing this problem with the following but now we don't know how to grab the data for each dropdown since name is usually a string that we can call:

```
const options = [
    {
        label: '1',
        value: '1'
    },
    {
        label: '2',
        value: '2'
    },
    {
        label: '3',
        value: '3'
    },
    {
        label: '4',
        value: '4'
    },
    {
        label: '5',
        value: '5'
    },
    {
        label: '6',
        value: '6'
    },
    {
        label: '7',
        value: '7'
    },
    {
        label: '8',
        value: '8'
    },
    {
        label: '9',
        value: '9'
    },
    {
        label: '10',
        value: '10'
    }
];
```

```
{
   Header: 'Proficiency',
        accessor: 'name',
        Cell: ({value}) => (
        <FormGroup>
          <Field
             component={Select}
             name={value}
             label=""
             options={options}
             validate={required}
         />
       </FormGroup>
     )
},
```

We tried fixing this problem with the following but now we don't know how to grab the data for each dropdown since name is usually a string to capture the data using formValueSelector like the following:

```
 let templateFormData = formValueSelector('templateForm')(
        state,
        'name',
        'description',
        'cosa',
        'department',
        'suppliers'
    );
```

Any idea how to fix this?